# Is there a way to see the query produced by ReactiveSearch

Tags: reactjs, reactivesearch

I'm working on a project with reactive search and I want to see the query produced. Can that be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can see the prevQuery and nextQuery using `onQueryChange` prop. Also in `v3` you can use `StateProvider` to get the detail of any component by passing the respective `componentId`.

Do check the docs [here](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/base-components/stateprovider.html).